# scala - count every line in which a word occurs

Tags: scala, mapreduce, map-function

I want to find create a Map that has a word as a key and a List of integers as a value. 
The Integers in the list should represent the line numbers as indices. Like so:

```
Map("test" -> List(0, 2), "test2"->List(1),"foo" -> List(0, 3), "bar" -> List(2))
```

This would mean that the word test occurred in line 0&2, foo in line 0&3 and bar only in line 2.
I already managed to create a list of all words that occur in one line of text and read them to a list e.g.

```
val wordsWithLine= List((0,"test"), (0,"foo"), (1,"test2"), (2,"test"), (2,"bar"), (0,"test"), (3,"foo"))
```

Now I'm stuck and have no Idea how I can create this map. I know that the function definition has to look like this, but I have no idea how to implement it:

```
def createIndexMap(listwithIndices: List[(Int, String)]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {???}
```

My idea was to use `groupMapReduce()` ? But I can't wrap my head around how this works.

I'm very new to Scala and functional programming in general so any tips would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `groupMap`

```
def createIndexMap(listwithIndices: List[(Int, String)]): Map[String, List[Int]] =
  listwithIndices.groupMap(_._2)(_._1)
```

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to group by word, then map the result so that key is still a word but value is a distinct list of line numbers:

```
listwithIndices.groupBy(wWI => wWI._2).map(group => group._1 -> group._2.map(item => item._1).distinct)
```

I suggest to play with this code in scala interactive shell to figure out how exactly it works.

It is possible to do it may other (more succinct) ways (using groupMap or groupBy and mapValues).